# Find user position with a timeout

Tags: android, gps

I need to find the user position with a timeout, then I wrote a code like this

1. Start a LocationListener

   ```
   GPSLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            _timerGPSLocation.cancel();
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle b) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
   }
   };

    _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, _GPSLocationListener);
   ```

   `
2. Setup a timer for the timeout

   ```
   _timerGPSLocation = new Timer();
   _timerGPSLocation.schedule( new TimerTask() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       _locationManager.removeUpdates(_GPSLocationListener);
   }

   }, (long)(timeout*1000) );
   ```

I think that doing this (trying to read coordinates and setup a timer with timeout) for many times can let the GPS contact some satellites and give me the right location.
There is a better way for doing this? 
Calling _locationManager.removeUpdates on the timeout will remove all contacted satellites?

EDIT:

My goal is to read the GPS at regular intervals (5 minutes). I need also to set a timeout while try to get the location using GPS read. if no location is read after the timeout I need to stop the location listener. I've achieved this using the code liste here.

Now my question is if removing the LocationListener because it's go in timeout will cause the loss of the "acknowledgement" between the GPS and the satellite.

Comment: Are you trying to get GPS updates at regular intervals? if not then I am slightly confused

Comment: I try to read the GPS at regular intervals (5 minutes), but want to have a timeout on the GPS read (30secs), if no location is read after the timeout want to stop the location listener.

Comment: I would take advantage of the onStatusChanged method in the location listener then. That method is called if something like the GPS is unavailable, if it will be right back up, or if it is available. It will be called once you start requesting updates so if you put an if statement in there you can tell if its available. the page for that is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduling a timer would work for what you're trying to do. Similarly you could use a handler and pass it a thread or a Looper object. As in

`Handler h = new Handler();`

`h.postDelayed(Runnable r, long millis);`

With that you could also post a runnable, i.e thread or looper at a time delay to cancel location updates.

EDIT: postDelayed is used for a runnable to run after a certain delay. postAtTime posts at a certain uptime of the program

Comment: Note also that its a handler from android.os not from java.util.logging

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But I want to known if adding/removing the LocationListener while it's go in timeout will cause the loss of the "acknowledgement" between the GPS and the satellite.

Comment: Well yeah. Removing the listener means that you are not going to receive any updates from the GPS because you no longer need them. But as soon as you call request location updates again the "acknowledgement" will once again be there.

Comment: Ok, I want to liten this: "But as soon as you call request location updates again the "acknowledgement" will once again be there.". Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but I'm not sure if I know what you mean by "OK, I want to liten this"

Comment: Do you mean you want to hear more about it? like how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I want to hear more about this argument, about the optimizing and strong way for get the position with GPS having a timeout (when getting the position take more time then the timeout my function has to stop and return null). Thanks a lot!